# Assigning Workflow to Meeting Agenda

Tags: workflow, meeting-workspace

**What I'm trying to accomplish** is a recurring meeting that people can submit agenda ideas for, but those ideas have to be approved before ending up in the final agenda.

The ideal solution for me would be to combine the OOTB Approval Workflow with a Meeting Workspace. Whenever someone edits a workspace event instance (notably: adds an agenda to it), an approval workflow is generated and sent out. Once that approval happens, then the agenda item is added.

**The problem is** that the Workflows buttons are disabled when I'm inside the meeting workspace, and the approval workflow I have attached to the parent calendar doesn't activate when changes are made to the workspace agendas. I tried going into Designer and associating the Approval WF to the Agenda List, but that results in an "unexpected error." This brings me to my question...

**How can I associate a workflow to a meeting's agenda?**